# Why it is good or bad idea to add "Change Tracking of fields" to Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, dapper

We are using `Dapper` and `Dapper.Contrib` in our application. We choose `Dapper` because it is faster and speed is everything to us due to heavy load. And now it seems **"Change tracking of fields"** is vital for us. And for now `Dapper.Contrib` creates `update` query which sets all fields always and such queries make them slower. Some tables now have ~30 columns and fully updating rows in that tables are very inefficient.

As I see `Dapper.Contrib` has `Change tracking per object`, but `Change tracking per field` is not introduced to the library.

I did a research very carefully and find out that no work is done in that area. That luckless research confused me. I would like to hear your thoughts:

1. If such extension is not implemented then may be it is not useful? What I am missing here?
2. Please put yourself into my shoes. What would you do? Move to EF or introduce "Chnage tracking" to Dapper.Contrib?
3. May be adding such feature will make Dapper slow and that's why that feature is not implemented yet?

Answer (score 4):

Dapper.Contrib can do change tracking if you use the `Get` and `Update` methods, and you hand `Update` the same object (after you make changes to it) that you retrieved using `Get`.

Change tracking per field is inconsequential.  Change one field and you still have to write the entire record.

If you really only want to change a single field (or two...) without incurring the cost of writing the entire record, you have to do this:

```
conn.Execute(
    @"UPDATE MyTable SET MyField=@myParameter WHERE ID = @id",
    new { myParameter = myNewValue, id=myID });
```

Note: You might find support for per-field change tracking [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/1204).  It's not in Dapper because:

> This isn't a direction we want to go with Dapper. If you want full change tracking or updates for objects I would recommend one of the ORMs that accepts these additional costs associated with change tracking like Entity Framework. It's just not something we want in the core Dapper library. -- *Nick Craver*

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me. Of course I am aware of that. But we have tona of such updates. We don't want to write update query manually for each of them.

Comment: No, I understood your question perfectly.  If you want to go rogue, you could potentially apply [these changes](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/1204) to your own fork of Dapper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment. But my question is about pros and cons. It seems there are some cons and thats why such feature is not added. And i want to figure out possible reasons. Then I will figure out whether to add such feature or not

Comment: [Nick Craver's comment](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/1204#issuecomment-474336654) in that post I linked seems insightful: *"I want to say thanks for the contribution, but this isn't a direction we want to go with Dapper. If you want full change tracking or updates for objects I would recommend one of the ORMs that accepts these additional costs associated with change tracking like Entity Framework. It's just not something we want in the core Dapper library."*

Comment: And the original author of that post goes into his rationale [in detail](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/1204#issuecomment-477071439).

Comment: Good finding. It answersmy question partially.

Answer (score -2):

Try dapper raw sql or stored procedure instead of using Contrib's update? Just see if raw sql / stored procedure is faster or not. If it's faster than contrib's update, guess you need to use raw sql / stored procedure if you are concerned about performance.

If I were you, I would switch to EF Core. It's much faster and shorter time in development.